# Can you move a self-hosted WordPress blog into an existing WordPress.com blog?

Tags: migration

Is it possible to merge a self-hosted WordPress blog with a WordPress.com blog?  I need to move the self-hosted blog into an existing blog on WordPress.com.

I am aware of https://wordpress.com/support/import/import-an-entire-wordpress-site/ but it assumes you are starting from scratch.

Comment: You’ll need to ask WordPress.com support what their policies and processes are for migrations. Their service is technically third-party, and off topic here.